# Using bash script need to obtain the desired output

Tags: bash

I am having a file contains 4,000 lines were shown some of the lines below:

```
Sdppointer_u7
Sdppointer_gh6
Wsd_rt5
Wsd_p8
```

Where all lines will be `Sdppointer_*, Wsd_*`. It needs to print the output as shown below when the file encounters line with string's `Sdppointer_*, Wsd_*`. In below code t2 is the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
str1="SdpMaster*"
str2="Wsd*"
content=$(cat t2)
if [ "$str1" == "$content" ];then 
    echo "User A hitlist  " "$str1" "-rev" "B.9"
elif [ "$str2" == "$content" ];then
    echo "User A hitlist  " "$str2" "-rev" "A.7"
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

In my above code how can I make the str1, str2 to accept all the strings like `Sdppointer_*, Wsd_*`

Desired Output:

```
User A hitlist Sdppointer_u7 -rev B.9
User A hitlist Sdppointer_gh6 -rev B.9
User A hitlist Wsd_rt5 -rev A.7
User A hitlist Wsd_p8 -rev A.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like case statements for this sort of thing.

```
while read line
do case "$line" in
   SdpMaster*) echo "User A hitlist  " "SdpMaster*" "-rev" "B.9" ;;
         Wsd*) echo "User A hitlist  " "Wsd*"       "-rev" "A.7" ;;
            *) echo "Not found '$line'"                          ;;
   esac
done < tst
```

I added a line (3) that matched SdpMaster -

```
$: cat tst
Sdppointer_u7
Sdppointer_gh6
SdpMaster_ab1
Wsd_rt5
Wsd_p8
```

Output -

```
Not found 'Sdppointer_u7'
Not found 'Sdppointer_gh6'
User A hitlist   SdpMaster* -rev B.9
User A hitlist   Wsd* -rev A.7
User A hitlist   Wsd* -rev A.7
```

You could still use vars if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a while loop to go through all the lines.

```
bash-3.2$ cat sample
Sdppointer_u7
Sdppointer_gh6
Wsd_rt5
Wsd_p8

bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ SUB_A='Sdppointer'
bash-3.2$ SUB_B='Wsd'
bash-3.2$ while read lines
> do
> if [[ "$lines" == "$SUB_A"* ]]; then
>   echo "User A hitlist $lines -rev B.9"
> 
> elif [[ "$lines" == "$SUB_B"* ]]; then
>   echo "User A hitlist $lines -rev A.7"
> fi
> done < sample
User A hitlist Sdppointer_u7 -rev B.9
User A hitlist Sdppointer_gh6 -rev B.9
User A hitlist Wsd_rt5 -rev A.7
User A hitlist Wsd_p8 -rev A.7
bash-3.2$
```